# Select rows with duration calculation in the where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I need to find out how to `COUNT` the number of rows that match my query. Here is my database:

```
+----+---------------+---------------+----------+
| id | delivery_date | delivery_time | duration |
+----+---------------+---------------+----------+
| 1  | 2018-02-17    | 10:30:00      | 40       |
+----+---------------+---------------+----------+
| 2  | 2018-02-18    | 14:20:00      | 25       |
+----+---------------+---------------+----------+
| 3  | 2018-02-19    | 08:50:00      | null     |
+----+---------------+---------------+----------+
```

I have a `selectedDate` and a `selectedTime`. I want to see if it falls in the "duration" period, before and after.

So for example, if the `delivery_time` is `10:30:00` and the `duration` is 40, then it will subtract 40 and add 40 to the `delivery_time`. So then any time that falls between `09:50:00` - `11:10:00` will be counted as exists.

Also, if duration does not exist or is null, then only the `delivery_time` itself will be counted.

Here is my code (just an example, is not production safe, includes vulnerabilities):

```
/////// Expected Output //////

$selectedDate1 = '2018-02-18';
$selectedTime1 = '14:35:00';
// Exists


$selectedDate2 = '2018-02-18';
$selectedTime2 = '14:50:00';
// Does not exist


$selectedDate3 = '2018-02-17';
$selectedTime3 = '09:50:00';
// Exists


$selectedDate3 = '2018-02-19';
$selectedTime3 = '08:50:00';
// Exists

////// Expected Output End //////


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deliveries
    WHERE delivery_date = $selectedDate# AND
    (delivery_time = $selectedTime# AND duration IS NULL)
    OR
    (delivery_time +-= duration = $selectedTime# AND duration IS NOT NULL)
);
```

Obviously the `delivery_time +-= duration` needs to be fixed/revised. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. It checks that the delivery date matches the selected date, and then checks that either the delivery time is the same as the select time (there is no need to check if `duration IS NULL` as this is a valid condition for when `duration IS NOT NULL` too), or if the selected time falls inside the delivery window (delivery_time +/- duration).

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM deliveries
WHERE delivery_date = @selectedDate
  AND (delivery_time = @selectedTime OR
       @selectedTime BETWEEN delivery_time - INTERVAL duration MINUTE
                         AND delivery_time + INTERVAL duration MINUTE);
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gsu4xGqw8Yi4e2c5JjMrWV/0)

Comment: Awesome work man, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!